# What happens if logstash sends data to elasticsearch at a rate faster than it can index?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

So I have multiple hosts with logstash installed on each host. Logstash on all these hosts reads from the log files generated by the host and sends data to my single aws elasticsearch cluster.

Now considering a scenario where large quantities of logs are being generated by each host at the same time. Since logstash is installed on each host and it just forwards the data to the es cluster I assume that even if my elasticsearch cluster is not able to index it, my hosts won't be affected. Are the logs just loss in such a scenario?

Can my host machines get affected in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you may lose some logs on the host machines, and that's why messaging solutions like kafka are used https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/deploying-and-scaling.html#deploying-message-queueing

Comment: But it won't slow my host machines down for sure ?